# Is a function on a compact subset of $\mathbb R$ bounded?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a function. Let $ S \subset \mathbb R$ be compact.

Is it true that the image of $S$ i.e. $f(S)$ is bounded?

What if f is assumed to be measurable? Is the image bounded in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not even if $f$ is measurable. Consider $S=[0,1]$ and
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}n&\text{if }x=\frac1n\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases} $$

(Of course, if $f$ is continuous, then $f(S)$ is compact and hence bounded).

Comment: It's a great counterexample. Thanks.